# Complexification of $\mathbb{Z}$ using tensor products

Tags: field-theory, modules, tensor-products, extension-field

I would just like a brief explanation of how to evaluate, the following tensor product when the vector space $V$ is replaced by the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$.

$$    ? = V\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} $$

Comment: As $\mathbb{Z}$ is not an $\mathbb{R}$-module, you can't take the tensor product over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: also if you post as an answer ill gladly give u credit for it.

Comment: Upvoted to negate downvote, but it isn't worth a positive value. (because it's a misconception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be a ring. Given a right $R$-module $M$ and a left $R$-module $N$, we can form their [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules) denoted $M\otimes_R N$. If $R$ is a field, then a module over $R$ is simply a vector space over that field.

As $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, it is not an $\mathbb{R}$-module, so the expression $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$ is meaningless.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. This is exactly what i thought to be true. just needed to hear someone else say it i suppose!